# How do I insert values from a hash into a database using Perl's DBI module?

Tags: perl, dbi

I need to insert values from a hash into a database. Following is the code template I have to insert values in table1 column *key* and *value*:

```
use DBI;
use strict;

%hash; #assuming it already contains desired values
my $dbh = DBI->connect(
      "dbi:Sybase:server=$Srv;database=$Db", 
      "$user", "$passwd"
) or die sprintf 'could not connect to database %s', DBI->errstr;
my $query= "Insert INTO table1(key, values) VALUES (?,?) ";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($query) 
    or die "could not prepare statement\n", $dbh->errstr;
$sth-> execute or die "could not execute", $sth->errstr;
```

I know how to insert values using array i.e use `execute_array()`, but do not know how to insert values present in `%hash` in table1.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly does `%hash` contain?

Comment: how does that matter? it is defined exactly the way a hash should be defined.

Comment: The structure of the hash is an important part of the question. You already have two different answers, from people who understood the question differently, because it's not clear what's inside the hash.

Comment: %hash is defined as $key,$value.

Comment: Your answers are so incredibly **not** helpful that it makes me wonder why you refuse to give us that information. You do realize that `$value` could be just about anyhting?

Comment: There's [an example](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm#prepare_cached) in [the docs](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm)

Comment: @Manni: my bad for not realizing what was asked. $value are pure int numbers, without any character or anything else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following uses the `execute_array` function as mentioned in your question. I tested it.

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=$DB;host=$host;port=$port", $user, $password);

my %hash = (
            1   =>  'A',
            2   =>  'B',
            0   =>  'C',
            );

my @keys = keys %hash;

my @values = values %hash;

my $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO table1(id, value) VALUES (?,?);");

$sth->execute_array({},\@keys, \@values);
```

(Sorry, I don't have a Sybase database to work with, or I'd use it as an example.)

Answer (score 2):

Try [SQL::Abstract](http://search.cpan.org/~ribasushi/SQL-Abstract-1.81/lib/SQL/Abstract.pm)

```
use DBI;
use SQL::Abstract;
use strict;

%hash; #assuming it already contains desired values
my $dbh = DBI->connect(
      "dbi:Sybase:server=$Srv;database=$Db", 
      "$user", "$passwd"
) or die sprintf 'could not connect to database %s', DBI->errstr;

my ($query, @bind) = $sql->insert("tableName", \%hash);
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($query) 
    or die "could not prepare statement\n", $dbh->errstr;
$sth-> execute (@bind) or die "could not execute", $sth->errstr;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a mostly easy way to build the query.  I will typically do something like this because I haven't found another workaround yet.

```
use strict;
use DBI;

my $dbh = Custom::Module::Make::DBH->connect('$db');

my %hash = (
    apple  => 'red',
    grape  => 'purple',
    banana => 'yellow',
);

my $keystr = (join ",\n        ", (keys %hash));
my $valstr = join ', ', (split(/ /, "? " x (scalar(values %hash))));
my @values = values %hash;

my $query = qq`
    INSERT INTO table1 (
        $keystr
    )
    VALUES (
        $valstr
    )
`;

my $sth = $dbh->prepare($query) 
    or die "Can't prepare insert: ".$dbh->errstr()."\n";

$sth->execute(@values)
    or die "Can't execute insert: ".$dbh->errstr()."\n";
```

But it's possible I also didn't understand the question correctly :P

Comment: The problem I see with this approach is that one might run into the trap of not properly escaping the parameters. I always recommend using the placeholders! Other than that, good idea.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out.  I just made an update to the code above that resolves that issue. Sorry for missing that.

Comment: sorry if this is a silly question but Custom::Module::Make::is supposed to be changed according to the location of your DBH right?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try using

```
for my $key (keys %hash) {
  $sth->execute($key, $hash{$key}) or die $sth->errstr;
}
```

Is this what you're trying to achieve?

If I understand the [manual](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.609/DBI.pm#execute) correctly ("Execute the prepared statement once for each parameter tuple (group of values) [...] via a reference passed ...") it should also be possible to simply to

```
($tuples, $rows) = $sth->execute_array(\%hash) or die $sth->errstr;
```