# How can I insert hash values in columns with Perl's DBI?

Tags: perl, dbi

I have a hash and I am trying to insert its values into database. Hash is defined as follows:

```
my %hash = (
            1   =>  'First Word',
            2   =>  'Second Word is correct',
            0   =>  'Third word does not exist',
            );
```

I do not know how to insert values in a database using hashes. I notice my question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798861/how-do-i-insert-values-from-a-hash-into-a-database-using-perls-dbi-module) question. But, none of the answers seem to be correct. On using any of the listed answers, the values in hash are not inserted, instead reference to hash is inserted i.e. `ARRAY(0x9e63b30)`. But when I `print Dumper @values`, values get printed and not reference values.

Any suggestions on how to insert values and not their reference? And, what is going wrong in the solutions listed in answers to [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798861/how-do-i-insert-values-from-a-hash-into-a-database-using-perls-dbi-module).

@values is defined same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798861/how-do-i-insert-values-from-a-hash-into-a-database-using-perls-dbi-module) question i.e.

```
my @values = values %hash;
```

Edit:
Db structure:

T1:

```
sid  sentence
1    First Word
2    Second Word is correct
0    Third word does not exist
```

in above sid is `keys` of hash and sentence is `values` of hash.

this is what I tried out (it is one of the answers to [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798861/how-do-i-insert-values-from-a-hash-into-a-database-using-perls-dbi-module)):

```
my @keys = keys %hash;

my @values = values %hash;

my $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO T1(sid, sentence) VALUES (?,?);");

$sth->execute_array({},\@keys, \@values);
```

again, while inserting `@values` reference values are getting inserted.

EDIT:

_ *OUTPUT* _

```
$VAR1 = 'First Word';
$VAR2 = 'Third word does not exist';
$VAR3 = 'Second Word is correct';
```

_ *CODE* _
this is how I am inserting values into %hash

```
my $x=0;
foreach my $file(@files){
        if ($file =~ /regex/){
                push(@{$hash{$x}}, "$1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7"); 
        }
        elsif ($file =~ /regex/){
                push(@{$hash{$x}}, "$1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6");
        }
        elseif ($file =~ /Hs_(.+)_(.+)_(.+)_(.+)_(.+)_W.+txt/){
                push (@{$hash{$x}}, "$1 $2 $3 $4 $5");
        }
$x++;
}
```

Comment: All of the answers to that othe question are correct. Do you really need help updating a datbase or do you need help working with the Perl standard-data-structures?

Comment: @Manni: If the answers are correct then, why do reference values get uploaded in db instead of actual values?

Comment: Show us some code: at least the sql statement and the execute statement. And then tell us about your database. We have now idea how you want those values to end up in your db. Do the keys denote rows, colums or neither?

Comment: Show the output of `print Dumper \@values`

Comment: May we see more of your code please? It sounds like there is a simple error somewhere, especially since you have apparently tried three different valid ways of doing it. Simple typing errors have caused me great puzzlement at times.

Comment: The insertion of data into the hash seems to have nothing to do with your original creation of the hash. Why are you so reluctant to show us your code?

Comment: i have shown the whole code here. my code creates hashes and then inserts their value into databases and that is exactly what i have shown here.

Comment: Then where did the hash keys $a and $x come from?

Comment: $x is just a variable, defined as $x=0; I corrected the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not what you originally posted!!!  You have a hash of reference to arrays.  Read the perl reference tutorial (perlreftut) to learn about them.

(Use the command

```
perldoc perlreftut
```

to access this tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
my $key;
my $value;
while (($key, $value) = each %hash) {
    $sth->bind_param(1, $key);
    $sth->bind_param(2, $value);
    $sth->execute();
}
```

Comment: It's much better to write that loop as `while( my ( $key, $value ) = each %hash )`

Comment: no still the reference is getting uploaded instead of actual values.

Comment: Print out $key and $value in the loop to see if the values obtainerd from the hash are correct.

Comment: Also note that I'm using execute not execute_array

Comment: $key is correct but $value is getting printed as reference value i.e. ARRAY(0x949f6b0). What is going wrong?

Comment: FYI the authoritative reference to Perl DBI is found at <a href="http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI/DBI.pm"> </a>

Comment: @birdy: you have a hash of arrays.

Comment: fyi

<code>
#!/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash = (
            1   =>  'First Word',
            2   =>  'Second Word is correct',
            0   =>  'Third word does not exist',
            );
my $key;
my $value;
while (my ($key, $value) = each %hash) {
    print ("key: >$key< value: >$value<\n");
}
</code>
produces
<code>
key: >1< value: >First Word<
key: >0< value: >Third word does not exist<
key: >2< value: >Second Word is correct<
</code>
under cygwin and perl 5.10.0

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

I suggest that you grab one of the functional examples from the previous [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798861/how-do-i-insert-values-from-a-hash-into-a-database-using-perls-dbi-module) and get it working on your machine with your database. Once you can get one of these examples working then you should be able to fix your own code.

**Previous answer:**

My reply on the other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798861/how-do-i-insert-values-from-a-hash-into-a-database-using-perls-dbi-module) that uses `execute_array()` also works, I tested it before posting it.

Comment: it works, but ,as i mentioned, it uploads reference values instead of actual values.

Comment: i added some more part of my code. added how im creating %hash